# What do OpenCL contexts mean? Why do they make sense?

Tags: opencl

The OpenCL API involves creating an "execution context", with many API calls require both a context and a device ID.

But what's the use in those? We create contexts using an array of devices. Isn't it a very artificial construct? I mean, if we would have, say, all devices sharing some common memory space as a pre-defined context, then I guess it makes some sense. But otherwise - why not just have device-specific OpenCL APIs ignore contexts altogether, while multi-device-related APIs happen at the platform level?

Now, if you tell me "oh, but context have X or do Y which devices and platforms don't" - please explain why X or Y should not be at device-context or at platform-context. The [clCreateContext reference page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html) (OpenCL 1.2) lists:

- *command queues*: device-specific.
- *memory*: could be multi-device, but since the choice of devices into the context is arbitrary, it doesn't seem like the right abstraction.
- *program and kernel objects*: why is this not device-specific? (or maybe - device and user specific?)
- used for *"executing kernels on one or more devices specified in the context"*: not clear what's wrong with that being device-specific (or platform-scope if we care about synchornization more).

PS - CUDA also has "contexts", but those are thread-specific and device-specific, and encapsulate policies such as "should this thread block when synchronizing?" or "should this thread yield after scheduling GPU work" etc.)

Comment: CUDA has always had the similar concept of context. This level of control is given to you by the driver api http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g65dc0012348bc84810e2103a40d8e2cf. The runtime API holds a single context that can be accessed by the driver API. A use of multiple contexts is the ability to destroy one without doing a cudaDeviceReset.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: I'll edit my answer, but that's a per-device context, i.e. multiple contexts <-> one device, not multiple <-> multiple like in OpenCL. Also, those CUDA contexts are thread-specific.

Comment: Well, OpenCL is a standard. I believe they left room for some features discussed during meetings when Gemini designs or other implementers would want to benefit some level of shared memory. To my knowledge, this is not implemented that way on CUDA, but OpenCL is implemented by others. This turns into discussion/opinion.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: But even room for other features has some reasoning behind it. Could you give a meaningful example of how this kind of contexts (multi-device, not thread-specific) might be useful?

Comment: It is possible to create more than a Context, one/kernel and use results of separate kernelss between them?. Do anybody have of an useful example using more than one context?

Answer (score 3):

Why a context needs devices as a parameter? Because some platforms have multiple devices (ie: AMD has a CPU device as well as the GPU one). If you remove that functionality then the only options are:

- **Buffers are per-device only**:
  Which means that there is no possibility to use multiple devices in a CL program. Or it is, but you need explicit copy between them.

  - Seems ok at first. But try to do explicit copy in a 8 GPU system. Calls may also return OutOfMemory and crash your app if you don't first erase buffers from a particular GPU. Either your app is perfectly balanced, or the chances that a particular GPU bottlenecks and saturates its memory are very high. It is much easier to let the API handle all the copies for you.
- **Buffers are per-plaform**:
  Which means, in a single GPU application, you will need to specify where the buffer should be copied.
  The solution may again be, explicit copy. Same problems as before.

Additionally, contexts provide the same abstraction as GL contexts, isolate all the "soft" resources you are using, and clean and destroy everything inside them when destroyed.

If the application that created the context object is killed or SEG_FAULTS it is easy to de-allocate the resources or that app, without affecting any other application running in parallel.

---

Also:

> program and kernel objects: why is this not device-specific? (or maybe - device and user specific?)

**Kernels are already device specific**, since they are specific instances of a function inside a program and a given device.

You may have any arbitrary amount of kernels made with the same program, but with different arguments. This is very useful and makes sense, instead of having a single kernel object and change its arguments in every single call, it makes more sense to use multiple kernel instances.